# How to get the max and min of a data from child table with mysql and php?

Tags: php, mysql

Lets take an example:

I have 2 tables as below

[image: Main tables in database]

Child table is related to parent table using P_Id.

Parent table contains one row for each case.
Child table stores actions on each case and related by P_id, datetime colums records the time of action.

Now,
I want to **query what is the max of each case**, as below

[image: Result of max table]

Second thing I want to **get is max and min of each case in same table**
can it be done by only mysql or do i have to do using php also.

Result that I expect is as below:

[image: Result of max and min of each case]

Like this there are 1000's of rows in the table. Do i need to use python or something else to process this kind of data.

Comment: You can do this in mysql alone.

Answer (score 0):

Use max() and min() aggregate functions and for max check if it is the same as min and return null if they are the same:

```
select data, min(sub_data), if(min(sub_data)=max(sub_data), null, max(sub_data)
from parent p
inner join child c on p.id=c.p_id
```

Answer (score 0):

For your first thing:

```
SELECT
    p.data, c.sub_data, c.`datetime`
FROM parent p
JOIN child c
ON p.id = c.pid
JOIN (
    SELECT max(`datetime`) as `datetime`, pid
    FROM child
    GROUP BY pid
) c1
on p.id = c1.pid AND c.`datetime` = c1.`datetime`;
```

and second thing is:

```
SELECT
    p.data,
    cmin.sub_data as Min(sub_data),
    case when cmin.sub_data = cmax.sub_data then null else cmax.sub_data end as Min(sub_data)
FROM parent p
JOIN (
    SELECT max(`datetime`) as `maxdatetime`, min(`datetime`) as `mindatetime`, pid
    FROM child
    GROUP BY pid
) c
on p.id = c1.pid
JOIN child cmax
ON p.id = cmax.pid AND c.`maxdatetime` = cmax.`datetime`
JOIN child cmin
ON p.id = cmin.pid AND c.`mindatetime` = cmin.`datetime`
```